# Unable to build some projects in solution?

Tags: c#, linux, build, mono, project

I am getting the following message, which I'm not able to track down to a configuration.  There are some relevant articles, but none seem to answer.

Build failed.  Unknown LangVersion string ' '

If I look at the build properties for the project, it throws an exception, which appears to be the cause of the build error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: Unknown LangVersion string ''
  at MonoDevelop.CSharp.Project.CSharpCompilerParameters.get_LangVersion () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.CSharp.Project.CompilerOptionsPanelWidget..ctor (MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject project) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.CSharp.Project.CompilerOptionsPanel.CreatePanelWidget () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Dialogs.OptionsDialog.CreatePageWidget (MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Dialogs.SectionPage page) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Dialogs.OptionsDialog.ShowPage (MonoDevelop.Ide.Extensions.OptionsDialogSection section) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Dialogs.OptionsDialog.OnSelectionChanged (System.Object s, System.EventArgs a) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.Signal.ClosureInvokedCB (System.Object o, GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.SignalClosure.Invoke (GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback (IntPtr raw_closure, IntPtr return_val, UInt32 n_param_vals, IntPtr param_values, IntPtr invocation_hint, IntPtr marshal_data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Do I have to indicate a language somewhere in monodevelop settings?  Is this spoken language or a programming language?

Comment: Try checking the language version in the project settings. Change to something else then back to Default.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/langversion-compiler-option

Comment: Tried this.  Same results

Comment: If you open the csproj file in text editor do you see <LangVersion>Default</LangVersion>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by upgrading to Mono 5.10

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
>
> echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu trusty main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install mono-devel